# Orderby datetime query in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a rest service which has a list of students each student has a datetime attached to there creation.

On my client side I want to order by this datetime from newest first, on my client side the code looks like this:

```
   public FindStudent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string uriGroups = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Student";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroups);
```

And it lists students by first created, I thought for a moment I could have added in an orderby query into the foreach var node but I dont think that will work, is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: What does this got to do with WCF, XAML, REST or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML as follows

```
var temp = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Students")
orderby Convert.ToDateTime(feed.Element("CreatDate").Value) descending
select new Student
{
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(feed.Element("ID").Value),
    //rest of the properties
};
```

Comment: I cant use a select statement in a foreach loop tho.

Comment: Get the collection of Student in intermediate data structure (before your foreach loop), get it sorted and then you can play with it in your foreach loop.

Comment: XElement can be converted to DateTime: `(DateTime)feed.Element("CreatDate")`

Answer (score 0):

in order to sort something based on date and time you need to convert it to date and time in your for-each loop you just loop through the pure text taken from xml document it not going to get ordered since it text an but you can create a student class with varaibles  `Studentid, FirstName LastName" TimeAdded TimeAdded` loop through the document again write every information to the object student add every object to the list sort the list the way you would like and then I think it should display in order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroups); 
var sortedXdoc = xDoc.Descendants("Student")
               .OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("TimeAdded").Value));
```